# The strangest thing with ob_start and headers

Tags: php, header, document, ob-start

ob_start and all the headers did not work on my webpage. I searched though my whole code and did not find anything wrong. Then I deleted all my code and placed a Header Location at the top of the dokument and it still didnt work so then I simply created a new document copied the code from the old document and then all of sudden it started to work.

Do any of you understand why this phenomenon occur?

Answer (score 0):

Which editor did you used? I also faced that kind of problem with Notepad++ 5.x. In my case, I changed document encoding from UTF-8 to ASCII and everything worked.

Comment: I used Dreamweaver CS4 but I open documents from time to time in Notepad when I'm going to do some fast changes.